Why does an element after an input look different when focused?
I can't figure out why this happens.
When I use the dev tools to investigate whether any properties on the div have changed, I don’t detect any modifications, and no class is added. There are no classes triggered on the :focus of the input. As shown in the example on the CodePen link, it seems to be behavior related to the browser.
I use Edge and chrome for the test. No problem with firefox.
text


form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
}

span {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
<form>
  <!-- text input with label on the left -->
  <span>
    <label for="apple">How do you like them apples?</label>
    <input type="text" id="apple" name="apple">
  </span>
  <div>Text weight</div>
</form>



I want the style to be consistent for div and span.

No repro here with Chrome

nothing happens for me in brave either (which is basically chrome as far as this is concerned)

In the snippet provided after the example code, the behavior does not occur, but it can be seen in the CodePen at the link: https://codepen.io/Federico-Segato/pen/ByBpBNa. With input:focus { outline: none; }, it does not appear. However, it does occur with input:focus { outline: 1px solid red; }. To me, it’s a mystery...

Are you talking about the weight of the text in the bottom becomes slightly lighter after the input is focused, after zooming in? If so I did see it on my Chrome 131.0.6778.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) but only on specific zoom ratio. Not sure what happened.

It’s exactly like this: the weight of the text below the input becomes slightly different when the input receives focus.

I think this question shouldn't be closed because it is reproducible. That being said, @FedericoSegato this might be a subpixel rendering problem. Forcing GPU rendering by adding will-change:transform on the span fixes it for me.
